# MYSQL group by custom interval

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, with datetime values in each row.

I try to group by  two intervals:

1. Date between now and now - 1hour
2. Date betwwen now - 1 hour and now - 2 hour

What i do?

```
SELECT MIN(date), MAX(date), count(stats.ID) as c FROM stats WHERE date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND NOW() GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) DIV 7200
```

| MIN(DATE) | MAX(DATE) | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-11 18:45:15 | 2023-03-11 18:59:59 | 150 |
| 2023-03-11 19:00:01 | 2023-03-11 19:45:15 | 250 |

and i try this:

```
SELECT count(ID),  MIN(date), MAX(date), sec_to_time(time_to_sec(date)- time_to_sec(DATE)%(60*60)) as intervals from stats WHERE date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AND NOW()group by intervals
```

| MIN(DATE) | MAX(DATE) | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-11 18:45:15 | 2023-03-11 18:59:59 | 150 |
| 2023-03-11 19:00:00 | 2023-03-11 19:59:59 | 250 |
| 2023-03-11 20:00:00 | 2023-03-11 19:45:15 | 250 |

Expected result

| MIN(DATE) | MAX(DATE) | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-03-11 18:45:15 | 2023-03-11 19:45:15 | 150 |
| 2023-03-11 19:45:15 | 2023-03-11 20:45:15 | 250 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample data and expected output would be helpful, but can't you just do:

```sql
SELECT MIN(`date`), MAX(`date`), COUNT(stats.ID) AS c,
    CASE
        WHEN `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
            THEN 1
        WHEN `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND NOW()
            THEN 2
    END AS grp
FROM stats
WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND NOW()
GROUP BY grp
```

or even just:

```sql
SELECT MIN(`date`), MAX(`date`), COUNT(stats.ID) AS c,
    IF(`date` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR, 1, 2) AS grp
FROM stats
WHERE `date` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND NOW()
GROUP BY grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT AGGREGATE_FN( CASE WHEN datetime_column BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW - INTERVAL 1 HOUR
                          THEN value_column
                          END) AS agg_now,
       AGGREGATE_FN( CASE WHEN datetime_column BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR AND NOW - INTERVAL 2 HOUR
                          THEN value_column
                          END) AS agg_before
FROM data_source
WHERE datetime_column BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW - INTERVAL 2 HOUR;
```

Comment: Thank for reply.  But, i need GROUP BY this  intervals. AND MYSQL 8 say AGGREGATE_FN does not exist

Comment: @АлександрГрешников o_O I give you a pattern. You must understand how it would work then apply it in your code.

Comment: @АлександрГрешников [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3 please.

Comment: `BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` should be `BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AND NOW()`

Comment: Yes, Your Right,  AND thank for solution way, BUT my query have  other (CASE END) conditions,  is there a way to get that result via GROUP BY?